# Permission management in abp framework

Tags: angular, permissions, abp

after login in as admin in angular UI template abp framework, I don't see the "identity management" submenu. What settings should I make on the permission side?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should access your project via /Identity/Users and give IdentityManagement authorizations to the specific user.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but when I do log in as admin, I can't see anything except the tenant manager, where can I find the permission page or menu?

Comment: Can't access the page by typing `/IdentityServer/Users` in the URL?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I can't find that. I know that I should assign the permission within the code or config file, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Can I know your project version so that I can replicate the problem?

Comment: Yes sure, ABP 7 template microservice with angular ui